# How to instantiate a class with asynchronous Firebase methods in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am instantiating a `User` class via a Firebase DataSnapshot. Upon calling the initializer `init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)`, it should asynchronously retrieve values from two distinct database references, namely `pictureRef` and `nameRef`, via the `getFirebasePictureURL` and `getFirebaseNameString` methods' @escaping completion handlers (using Firebase's `observeSingleEvent` method). To avoid the *'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized* error, I had to initialize `fullName` and `pictureURL` with temporary values of `""` and `URL(string: "initial")`. However, when instantiating the class via `User(snapshot: DataSnapshot)`, these values are never actually updated with the retrieved Firebase values.

```
import Firebase

class User {

 var uid: String
 var fullName: String? = ""
 var pictureURL: URL? = URL(string: "initial")

//DataSnapshot Initializer

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

self.uid = snapshot.key

getFirebasePictureURL(userId: uid) { (url) in

    self.getFirebaseNameString(userId: self.uid) { (fullName) in

        self.fullName = fullName
        self.profilePictureURL = url

    }
}

func getFirebasePictureURL(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL) -> Void) {

    let currentUserId = userId
    //Firebase database picture reference
    let pictureRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "pictureChildPath")

    pictureRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        //Picture url string
        let pictureString = snapshot.value as! String

        //Completion handler (escaping)
        completion(URL(string: pictureString)!)

    })

}


func getFirebaseNameString(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ fullName: String) -> Void) {

    let currentUserId = userId
    //Firebase database name reference
    let nameRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "nameChildPath")

    nameRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let fullName = snapshot.value as? String

       //Completion handler (escaping)
        completion(fullName!)

        })
     }
  }
```

> Is there a reason this is happening, and how would I fix this so it does initialize to the retrieved values instead of just remaining with the temporary values? Is it because `init` isn't asynchronous?

Edit: I am reading data from one node of the Firebase database and, using that data, creating a new node child. The method that initializes the User class will create this new node in the database as: [image]

As you can see, the children are updated with the temporary values so it seems the program execution does not wait for the callback.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There's an answer that may help but there appears to be a lot of unnecessary code here. Maybe it's needed but do you have a situation where you have a users uid, a users name and a profiile picture url stored in three separate firebase nodes? Also, you've got a class var *self.uid* which is well, a class var, there's not need to pass that to any functions since it's available to the entire class, and it's the first thing set. Are you calling your functions from outside the class?

Comment: @Jay Thanks! I realized my use of `uid` as an argument is unnecessary. The three data points are all children of a single node so a lot of this code is probably redundant. The get methods are not being called from outside the class--only upon instantiation of the class.

Comment: If all the data points are contained within one node then most of that code is unnecessary. Let me try an answer and see if that make the code more manageable for you.

Comment: Updated my answer but there's some unknowns in the question; why does *-Lomc6GG..." have a child node of *author*? What is the parent node? You're using callbacks but that may be unneeded, especially if your code is observing the node that contains the author data as it will be passed to your app via an event if a new author is added. One other thing about posting: We often need to use structures in answers, so they should be included as text so we don't have to retype them. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very hacky.

You should add `completionHandler` in `init` method. So, when your asynchronous call completed you will get actual value of object.

```
init(snapshot: DataSnapshot, completionHandler: @escaping (User) -> Void) {

    self.uid = snapshot.key

    getFirebasePictureURL(userId: uid) { (url) in

        self.getFirebaseNameString(userId: self.uid) { (fullName) in

            self.fullName = fullName
            self.profilePictureURL = url

            completionHandler(self)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is actually a quite idiomatic way to solve this problem, so I wouldn't consider is hacky. Upvoted

Comment: @SagarChauhan Thanks so much! If within a method, say `setUp()`, I initialize the class and get the callback from `FPUser`, would I have to use dispatch groups so the program waits on the callback within the method? E.g. `func setUp() { anotherFunction() ; FPUser { (user) in //do something with the user} }`

Comment: While I really like this answer, based on the comments from the OP and additional information it's now unrelated to the *actual* question. The OP is trying to pull data from two different nodes and combine them together and write out a third node so the completion handler here won't apply because it may or my not fire before reading the other node. Can you update?

Answer (score 3):

By the comments, it seems we could reduce the code considerably which will also make it more manageable

(SEE EDIT)

Start with a simpler User class. Note that it is initialized by passing the snapshot and then reading the child nodes and populating the class vars

```
class UserClass {
    var uid = ""
    var username = ""
    var url = ""

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        self.uid = snapshot.key
        self.username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullName").value as? String ?? "No Name"
        self.url = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "url").value as? String ?? "No Url"
    }
}
```

then the code to read a user from Firebase and create a single user

```
func fetchUser(uidToFetch: String) {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(uidToFetch)
    thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let user = UserClass(snapshot: snapshot)
            //do something with user...
        } else {
            print("user not found")
        }
    })
}
```

I don't know how the user is being used but you could add a completion handler if you need to do something else with the user outside the Firebase closure

```
func fetchUser(uidToFetch: String completion: @escaping (UserClass?) -> Void) {
    //create user
    completion(user)
```

**EDIT:**

Based on additional info, I'll update the answer. Starting with restating the objective.

The OP has two nodes, a node that stores user information such as name and another separate node that stores urls for pictures. They want to get the name from the first node, the picture url from the second node and create a new third node that has both of those pieces of data, along with the uid. Here's a possible structure for pictures

```
pictureUrls
   uid_0: "some_url/uid_0"
   uid_1: "some_url/uid_1"
```

and then we'll use the same /users node from above.

Here's the code that reads the name from /users, the picture url from /pictureUrls combines them together and writes out a new node with an /author child that contains that data and the uid.

```
func createNode(uidToFetch: String) {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(uidToFetch)

    let imageUrlRef = self.ref.child("pictureUrls")
    let thisUsersImageRef = imageUrlRef.child(uidToFetch)

    let allAuthorsRef = self.ref.child("allAuthors")

    thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let userName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"

        thisUsersImageRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { imageSnap in
            let imageUrl = imageSnap.value as? String ?? "No Image Url"

            let dataToWrite = [
                "full_name": userName,
                "profile_picture": imageUrl,
                "uid": uidToFetch
            ]

            let thisAuthorRef = allAuthorsRef.childByAutoId()
            let authorRef = thisAuthorRef.child("author")
            authorRef.setValue(dataToWrite)
        })
    })
}
```

The output to firebase is this

```
allAuthors
   -LooqJlo_Oc-voUHai3k //created with .childByAutoId
      author
         full_name: "Leroy"
         profile_picture: "some_uid/uid_0_pic"
         uid: "uid_0"
```

which exactly matches the output shown in the question.

I removed the error checking to shorten the answer so please add that back in and I also omitted the callback since it's unclear why one it needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have, however, clarified that the data snapshot passed into the init method is not the one which contains the `fullName` and `pictureURL`. It is the data snapshot of a different node in the database. I will update the post to clarify.

Comment: @SergioCharles Based on your update, I edited the question with a complete answer that matches the question.